# Regular Expression with Multiple Possible Replacements

Tags: .net, regex, translation, replace

I have some existing text that I need to replace with replacement text. The replacement text to be used depends on the existing text. Here's a simple translation table that shows my problem:

```
    ,'A',  ==> ,'Fred',
    ,'B',  ==> ,'Mary',
    ... and so on...
```

It's easy enough to match the original text. The part I'm having a problem with is the replacement text. As you can see, the replacement text depends on the matched text: If `,'A',` was found, I need to replace it with `,'Fred',`. Basically, I seem to need a translation table mechanism.

I'm using the .NET RegEx classes.

I understand capturing matches and re-using them in the replacement text but I don't think that's going to do the trick. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: `I'm using the .NET RegEx classes, although I don't think that matters.` --> It matters. Depending on the library, some operation are made possible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the .NET RegEx implementation, but I remember solving a similar challenge with Perl RegEx embedded functions, whereby I would just replace with a custom subroutine and pass the matched string. My sub routine would handle all the rules. Perhaps there is something similar in .NET RegEx??

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using .NET there are two approaches:

1. Multiple replacements:

   ```
   string.Replace("A", "Fred");
   string.Replace("B", "Mary");
   // ... (could use regex based replacement if necessary)
   ```
2. Pass a [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) delegate to `Regex.Replace` instead of the replacement string:

   ```
   Regex.Replace(input, matchRegexString, match => {
     // Code that takes a System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match and returns a string
   });
   ```

   and the return of the delegate is used as the replacement text. (There is also a non-static version where you create a `Regex` instance.) In the past I've done this to perform substitutions based on `%key%` in the input being looped up in a dictionary.

Comment: Note that option one becomes problematic if one replacement string contains another one which is search for later. (say `A` was replace with `Bert`, then due to the second line this would result in `A => Maryert`)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without multiple replacements and without delegates/subroutines, I believe, also only works if the substitution strings *already exist* "later" in your subject string.

Replace this:

```
,'A',(?=.*(Fred))|,'B',(?=.*(Mary))
```

With this:

```
,'$1$2',
```

Yes, a rather silly trick. Voting @Richard up to apologize for the silliness.